# Pin UIView just below UINavigationBar using Autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I need to pin a `UIView` just below the `UINavigationBar` (owned by `UINavigationController`) using Autolayout.

The tricky thing here is that the `UIView` needs to be a subview of the `UIApplication`'s main `UIWindow`.

The inserted view needs to track the position of the navigation bar, for example if the iOS status bar grows to double height (e.g. in the green "Return to call" scenario), or changes height as in landscape view.

The solution also needs to work with transparent `UINavigationBar`s where the view controller's `edgesForExtendedLayout` are not set to None.

Comment: Did you ever found out how to achieve this?

Comment: I never found a solution I was completely happy with, which didn't make assumptions about the current height of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `topLayoutGuide` as explained in [this Ray Wanderlich's tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110393/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial) (section **Layout Guides**)?

You should be able to achieve the desired outcome - and not have to compute the navBar height - with something like this:

```
let views = ["myView": myView, "topLayoutGuide":topLayoutGuide]

let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "V:[topLayoutGuide]-[myView(30)]",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: views)
```