# View and its subviews disappearing after adding constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a view (`addressLabelBackground`) at the top of my controller, underneath the navigation bar. It shows up fine in portrait mode, but I'm trying to get it to re-size when I turn the device to landscape mode.

So I attempted to add some constraints in storyboard by pinning `addressLabelBackground` to the left of the view (0), right of the view (0) and the top to the navigation bar (0), but when I run the application, the view and all its subviews disappear.

I also tried adding the constraints programmatically (like I did for the subviews), but again, `addressLabelBackground` and the subviews within disappear.

Here's the code (in `viewDidLoad`):
**Updated after answer, got a crash**

```
    view.addSubview(addressLabelBackground)
    addressLabelBackground.addSubview(addressLabel)
    addressLabelBackground.addSubview(turnToTechLogo)

    addressLabelBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    addressLabelBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    addressLabelBackground.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    addressLabelBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (navigationController?.navigationBar.bottomAnchor)!).isActive = true

    addressLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
    addressLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    addressLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addressLabelBackground.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    addressLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addressLabelBackground.topAnchor).isActive = true
    addressLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addressLabelBackground.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

The constraints for the addressLabel work perfectly fine in both portrait and landscape - it stays centered in the view. However when I try to add the constraints for `addressLabelBackground` the same way, or in storyboard, everything disappears.

How can I get this view to stay pinned underneath the navigation bar, and stretch its width to fit the width of the screen, when the device is in landscape mode?

EDIT (next day): Still trying to figure this out. I've tried making a subview called `innerContainer` and pinning it to the topAnchor of that:

```
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height-20)
    let innerContainer = UIView(frame: frame)

    self.view.addSubview(innerContainer)
    innerContainer.addSubview(addressLabelBackground)

    addressLabelBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addressLabelBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

But once again it disappears.

I've also tried pinning it to the top (0 points) of the topLayoutGuide in storyboard, and it disappears then too.

Comment: Is this your *complete* set of constraints? If not, please post the rest - they matter.

Comment: They were, although I took out the programmatic constraints because they weren't necessary. Now I just have `view.addSubview(addressLabelBackground)`. And in storyboard I have `addressLabel` and  `logo` placed within `addressLabelBackground`. For now those subviews stay put within `addressLabelBackground` regardless of orientation. However I still can't get the `addressLabelBackground` to resize to full width in landscape mode

Comment: Then you are missing some constraints on addressLabelBackground. You've given it a centerX and a top, but what's it's intrinsic width? Have you added a text attribute value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about text attribute value. And the problem seems to be if I give it any constraints at all, it (along with the subviews) disappear. Do you mean if I add certain constraints, it will resolve the problem?

Comment: As of now I have no constraints on anything and the logo and label are staying where they need to be within `addressLabelBackground`.

Comment: Labels have "intrinsic" width. You showed me that you (1) gave it a top constraint, and (2) a center X, but without either a text value (something like addressLabelBackground.text = "abc") or an *explicit* width constraint, that label has no width. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html

Comment: I set the width of the label in storyboard, just by sizing the label container appropriately. At this point I'm happy with the placement and sizing of the logo and label subviews, I'm just trying to get the `addressLabelBackground` (which is a rectangular view, almost like a header, that sits underneath the nav bar, and takes up the entire width of the screen in portrait mode) to be pinned underneath the nav bar, and remain the entire width of the screen, whether it's in portrait or landscape mode.

Comment: You had a good start. Give it three constraints - top, leading, trailing. I'll put in an answer. Let me know it it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your `addressLabelBackground` needs an auto layout that not only is pinned to the top, but to the sides of it's superview. Replace your existing `widthAnchor` constraint with these two:

```
addressLabelBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
addressLabelBackground.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: I got the crash: `'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x60000046cd00 "UIView:0x7fdcd460ce40.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x60000046cd80 "UINavigationBar:0x7fdcd4605900.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'`

Comment: That's your top constraint. The navigation bar isn't in the same hierarchy as the addressLabelBackground. Here's two SO questions that help show how to use a topMarginGuide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837957/is-it-possible-to-pin-a-uiviews-top-to-the-bottom-of-the-navigation-bar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568056/pin-uiview-just-below-uinavigationbar-using-autolayout

Comment: See my edit, I've tried several other approaches and this still doesn't seem to be possible, programmatically or in storyboard. Definitely frustrating - I'm not sure why it's so difficult to pin something to the bottom of the navigation bar.